# mysql_query SELECT giving me trouble

Tags: php, mysql

I cant really figure out whats wrong with this. I used to write the exact same thing and got it working.

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT encrypt FROM database WHERE word='$word'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Error returned is : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database WHERE word='asdaasdasdd'' at line 1

Comment: what is the value of $word ? $word = mysql_real_escape($word);

Comment: Did you try escaping with backticks?

Comment: Don't use reserved words as identifiers in the first place.

Comment: $word = strip_tags($word);
$word = stripslashes($word);

well the backticks solved the mystery. So helpful you guys are.

Comment: @Ken There is no reason not to use them. He just needs to enclose them with `\``. Altough in this case you are right. It seems strange to call a `table` a `database`, because it's just not.

Comment: @Basti - lol. I will be descriptive on the names from next time.

Comment: Using keywords as identifiers in any language is one of the dumbest things you can do.  There is absolutely no reason to ever ever do it...even if the language happens to give you gimmicks to cover up your mistake.  Why would you ever take the chance?  So you can show everyone you know that you can do it as long as you use backticks?  Silly.  There is just no reason when you have a virtually infinite number of other possible identifiers to choose from.

Comment: @KenThompson - Am sorry Ken, I am just getting into programming, and never knew it was a reserved keyword. :)

Comment: You don't need to apologize @Kishor.  Everyone makes that mistake eventually.  It can lead to some hard to track down problems because the compiler (or in this case the database) is usually not going to flag it and say "you used a keyword!".  Usually the message won't give you a clue.  It is just slightly annoying when someone (else) tries to justify taking a completely unnecessary risk so they can show how kewl they are that they know that you can use keywords with backticks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DATABASE` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), eclose it with backticks ``

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT encrypt FROM `database` WHERE word='$word'")
                     or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help buddy. That solved it. Added to my knowledge that database is a reserved word.

Comment: @Phil - Yeah, as soon as SO allows me. 5 more mins to go.

Answer (score 3):

Try backquoting `database`. It's probably a reserved word.

Comment: "database" is not *probably* a reserved word

Answer (score 2):

Database or Databases is a keyword. See the following link for [Reserve words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html)

Answer (score 1):

The or die() trick is a very poor choice for several reasons:

- It's not a very nice way to present the user with an error message.
- Using for instance the mysql_error() call with it, as many people do, exposes information that should never get output in a production environment
- You cannot catch the error in any way.
- You cannot log the error.
- You cannot control whether it should be output to the screen or not. It's okay to do that in a development environment, but certainly not in a production environment.
- It prevents you from doing any sort of cleanup. It just ends the script abruptly.

An easy way to implement is :

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT foo FROM bar', $db) or trigger_error('Query failed: ' . mysql_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Answer (score -1):

Encrypt is a function so, even tho' it is not causing the problem, I would avoid using it as a column name.